# How can I spice up my flat iOS icons?

Tags: icon, iphone, ios, applications

I'm making an icon for a speed reader app for the iPhone. These are more or less the designs I've been toying with:

[image]

Looking at them though, I just find they're a little boring. With the iOS 7 paradigm they seem to fit okay, but I just want them to be a little more exciting.

To illustrate what I mean, I really like the icon for Lumo:

[image]

It's very simple, similar to mine, but has a lot more character to the icon. I only don't like the long shadow thing.

How can I spice up my flat iOS icons? (I've tried really hard to avoid the word "pop" :))

Comment: I think the latter of your 3 options is the most 'iconic' and likely the path you want to pursue given that you like the Lumo icon.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you're looking for is very similar to this recent question:
[How to achieve a gradient in adobe illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19819/how-to-achieve-a-gradient-in-adobe-illustrator)

**The issue is that a lot of what seems flat in the latest UI trends really isn't.**
There are subtle gradients and hard edged shadows all over the place.

As I noted in the comments, I think the main thing you are noticing is how your very nice icon separates from the button shape: Yours looks like it's sitting within the shape, the Lumo example appears to float or protrude above.

On your green background you could

1. Add a subtle top to bottom gradient
2. Overlay that gradient with a hard-edged glass highlight
3. Add a hard-edged shadow dropping from the book at about 45°

Just those simple changes will have you much closer to your envied example.

Comment: Completely agree with this answer. Some decoration in the background layer can go a LONG way (but I think those icons are pretty neat as they are too).

Comment: I agree, the icons look really good. I think the piece that's bugging @DougSmith is simply getting the icon to stand above the button ground.