# How to make logo more 3D while flat?

Tags: logo, 3d, dimensions, flat-design

This is actually the very first logo I've designed (for my imaginary company).

I'd like to bring the optical illusion *(look closely, it looks like a cube)* up a bit, without any radical 3d bevels or shadows.

Google's *Material Design* guidelines are close to what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image: CDesign logo]

What would you suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I spice up my flat iOS icons?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20121/how-can-i-spice-up-my-flat-ios-icons)

Answer (score 5):

I think by tweaking the screen values to simulate natural light falling on an extruded bevel and adding "shadow" will add a bit of depth. I've enlarged the "C" to make the shadow illusion work better.

[image]

Or you could ramp it up a bit

[image]

Comment: It maybe looks a bit too natural and the optical illusion doesn't seem much stronger.

Comment: 13ruce has the right idea. Use the tint/shade of the shapes to create facets catching light. But don't do the weird shadow on the letter thing -- it's getting a little too literal there.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment that you are trying to accentuate the illusion that it's a 3D cube, I think what you need to do is light it as you would a cube...meaning each side of the cube would be getting a different amount of light. Here I lightened the top and darkened the right side (emulating being lit from the upper left).

[image]

Comment: Would the illusion be even stronger if you only used three shades of blue instead of six? (Maybe then the shades don't need to be as far from each other as you have here.)