# What's the name of this flat illustration style?

Tags: style-identification, flat-design

I want to buy some stock photos like the ones below. What is this design called?

I don't even know how to start searching...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we have name for these kind of "flat graphics" images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17350/do-we-have-name-for-these-kind-of-flat-graphics-images)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Flat vector illustration' is a very nice blanket term and should be a good start for your search query to find more of these. You might consider adding 'material design', Google's version of 'flat design'.

Though note that 'material design' is primarily a UI/interaction set of guidelines more than just an illustration style.