# What is this type of graphic design style called?

Tags: style-identification, style

What is the following type of graphic design style called?

[image]

Comment: Please read through our [style identification requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2931/23061) and edit your question to match them. Otherwise your question may be closed

Comment: @ZachSaucier It's not duplicate at all, I am not asking about the difference.

Comment: Whoops, I linked the wrong post. Possible duplicates http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17350/23061 and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/50437/23061

Answer (score 1):

Flat Design, or vector art if you like.

Here is  funny way to compare flat design and realism.

http://www.flatvsrealism.com