# What is the name of design language which contains flat humans shapes and semi-gradient shapes?

Tags: interface-design, gradient

Recently, lots of websites are using a new design method/language which combined from flat shapes with semi gradient style and flat human bodies?

eg: atlassian.com

eg2:

[image]

What is the name of this design language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the name of this flat illustration style?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50437/whats-the-name-of-this-flat-illustration-style)

Comment: Hello Pouya, your question has been put on hold as unclear. This is to prevent people giving an answer to a question that is not actually what you wanted to ask. Could you please [edit] you question to include more information, such as screenshots and examples of the exact style? And maybe look around the site for the names of similar styles and tell us why you don't think those fit? Thanks so much. Feel free to browse the site, ask more questions, answer questions and upvote quality content.

Comment: @PieBie But my question is clear and simple: what is the name of the method/design language which has semi-gradient shapes and human body shapes?

Comment: We are designers Pouya, we are very visual people, we like pictures, not words. Also, don't make us do work by visiting another site to answer your question. Please add some more examples and images. As it stands now, you're asking what the design system of Atlassian is called. For which you need to contact Atlassian.

Comment: There's no name for it. Somebody came up with this style, then many people replicated and now all these startup websites look like a template :)

Comment: There is usually no answer for this type of questions. There is no name in most cases. Having a name would imply that everything could be perfectly categorized. Now, this issue is a big problem in mechanical engineering, because you can not efficiently search for parts you can not name. Indeedif you can solve this, and play your hand well, then you can become a millionare easily. As this causes billions of lost revenue in inneficiency on a global scale.

Comment: @Lucian so then its "Late 10's startup style"

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exact name for design language but each company name their design system or design assets as their design language Like google name their material design as their design language. And the things about which you're asking these are illustrations.