# What is the correct style that describes the following images

Tags: svg, images, style-identification, stock-images

What is the name or names of the style used in the following images. They are used on Google, Facebook, [atlassian.com](https://www.atlassian.com/), [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/) and on info-graphics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I refer to them as lifestyle images but would like to search for these types of images but I do not know the correct term.

If I do a Google images search with the images I get the source of the image and not any information regarding the style.

Comment: first and foremost it's illustrations...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Vector Flat Design

> Flat design is a minimalistic design, clean, open space, crisp edges, bright colors and two-dimensional illustrations.

### Flat 2.0

> Flat 2.0 provides an allowance for subtle details and does not “outlaw” techniques – shadows, gradients, layering – that were not a part of flat design.

This brings as a novelty to Flat Design the sense of depth.

[image: Hey]
*Illustration by [Hey](https://www.handsomefrank.com/illustrators/hey) from www.handsomefrank.com*

Taking these two concepts as a basis, the type of image included in the question can be found in Google Search as **Vector Flat Landscapes** or **Vector Flat Scenes**

### Flat 3.0

There is a **Vector Flat 3.0** that keeps the same formal typology, trying to get away from the vectorial neat cleaning sensation with additions such as noise, grain, textures, spots, fog, scratches, splashes... and perspective. A vector photographic illustration. Some examples:

**[Michal Sawtyruk](https://michalsawtyruk.com/)**

[image]

**[Sam Ji](https://dribbble.com/SAMji_illustrator)**

[image]

**[Matthew Lyons](http://matthew-lyons.com/)**

[image]

**[Zak Steele-Eklund](https://dribbble.com/zakeklund)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, "Google Search as Vector Flat Landscapes or Vector Flat Scenes"  return the correct result.