# Finding a suggestion or real name for the new illustration style

Tags: vector, illustration, terminology, style-identification

It is common knowledge that *Flat Design* is getting outdated, the new illustrators are opening doors to several options that have been underestimated in recent years. While *Flat Design* appeared as a reaction to *Skeuomorphism*, where practically nullified all the techniques that this revealed, little by little the design is moving away from this rigidity, and, without going back, find a review of the techniques recently passed.

Following a scheme of these styles, and reviewing works of more avant-garde illustrators, the sequence could be the following:

#### Skeuomorphism

[image: Skeuomorphism]

*https://www.loungelizard.com/*

#### Flat Design

[image: Flat Design]

*[Jan Kallwejt](https://kallwejt.com/)*

#### Flat Design 2.0

[image: Flat Design 2.0]

*[Malika Favre](http://malikafavre.com/siempre-playa)*

#### New?

[image: New]

*[Michal Sawtyruk](https://michalsawtyruk.com/selected-works-may-2018)*

In [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/114410/120647) I answered naming the new design *Flat 3.0*, which obviously is not the right name. The new style is a consequence, renewal and advancement of flat design, but it almost has little or anything from Flat Design, beyond the exaltation of the vector images and the negation of bitmap effects ([Despite being made in Photoshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7i180bffNFA) ).

[image: MichalSawtyruk]

[*Michal Sawtyruk*](https://michalsawtyruk.com/virtual-plein-air-sketches-2)

[image: matthew-lyons]

*[Matthew Lyons](http://matthew-lyons.com/2011/12/sections-of-the-guide.html/garage)*

[image: Hey]

[*Hey Studio*](http://heystudio.es/projects/futerra-heathrow/)

This new style has no name, in Internet there are pages with descriptions or qualifying adjectives but there is no name that identifies it despite having a common technical and stylistic basis. I see parallelism in composition, colors and form with impressionism. I choose **Vector impressionism**.

[image: Le Suicidé]

***Le Suicidé***, Édouard Manet

[image]

***Last Dream***, Leonid Afremov

Although the evolution of Skeuom, Flat and Flat 2.0 was marked by the interface design, sure soon we will find web designs with this new style, or maybe there are already, any link?

Does anyone have an idea of ​​the real name or knowing a place to find a suggestion for the name of this new illustration style?

Comment: I like your proposed name - though I've a query: it seems almost like an intersection of impressionism, expressionism, cubism and pop art... and honestly there's more than a touch of the late 60's through mid eighties architectural illustration style mixed in too - is there a rubric in there we can mine for a neologism - a new word or name?

Comment: This is one of the objectives of the question. Names of many artistic styles emerged from debates, critics, journalists... Those who were criticized for painting as beasts (fauves) ended up calling themselves "fauvistes".

Comment: We *could* tie this to a stylistic originator from the turn of the previous century of course, with things like: Digi-Bernhardesque, Plakastil-digitale etc...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that tendencies evolution and styles are linear, but that was a nice explanation.

The examples you posted reminds me of a retro style of architectural visualizations of the 50's, and 70's. There are some stylistic elements, like a board brushstroke, but for me, the main element is:

**"Perspectivism", "Perspective 1.0" or "flat perspective"**

As the Avangard movements in the 20th century (or a lot of artistic movements for that matter), one main premise is to break pre-existing premises.

In this case, if you want to break the previous visual style of, not only flat but clearly 2 dimensional, the obvious choice would add depth, add perspective.

---

I remember this webpage that is now offline :( https://www.awwwards.com/sites/flat-design-vs-realism

and a previous tendency was the glossy and transparent effects. These examples explore more the perspective lines than the textures or the materials.

Another example of the post-flat style is isometric design: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=isometric+illustration&rlz=1C1GKLA_enMX664MX664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW3pni-7PdAhUHOawKHWn0CuAQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1012

These ones explore, again, perspective.

---

Edited:

Stealing user207001 idea, let's call it **"Perpe"**

Comment: The perspective element is true, as a reaction to flat. Regarding Isometric Style is before Flat Design, comes as a result of Pixel Art. One of the greatest examples of Isometric Style is [Habbo Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habbo), which has been in operation since 2000, [https://www.habbo.com](https://www.habbo.com/).

Comment: Isometric and a lot of styles we see today are much older. For example, we could see it applied to Escher's work. I am mentioning it as an evolution of the flat style applied to the web.

Comment: Of course, we are talking about digital styles.

Answer (score 2):

This opportunity must be used. One cannot very often suggest a name for a new style. My suggestion is Ogsloblob. Google doesn't know it. (How he could, this is a new thing).

My selection principle isn't new. A historical person named George Eastman hired in 1888 an advertising agency to find a name for his new products (=film for cameras and a camera for the film)). GE stated that the name must be totally new and it must not mean anything. The new name was Kodak.

Comment: If we're voting based on preference, I'd downvote this answer because "Ogsloblob" isn't very easy to pronounce or sound at all close to the style it's portraying

Comment: This answer brings me to the point that Michal Sawtyruk's illustrations seem like discarded Polaroids to me.

Comment: It's an interesting thought related to this thread that the driver behind many of the more recent changes in illustration style zeitgeist comes more and more from the world of concept illustration, conceptual design for video games and feature film CGI - and in many cases, the concept art aims for a certain "painterly-ness" or "inkyness" even whilst still being unabashedly digital. Maybe the new name should embody "conceptual art" somehow.