# What style features disproportionate figures, bright colours and noisy shadows?

Tags: illustration, style-identification

Some examples of what I mean:

*From Gmail:*
[image]

*From a video by Cosmin Serban:*
[image]

*From Eurowings in-flight magazine:*
[image]

*Also Eurowings in-flight magazine:*
[image]

*From The Goods by Vox:*
[image]

*Also from Vox:*
[image]

I have seen designs like this popping up everywhere, but when trying to search for it/tips on how to achieve a similar style, the only label I could find was broadly 'flat design' (or Flat Design 2.0, like in [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/114409/what-is-the-correct-style-that-describes-the-following-images), but which doesn't narrow down on the shapes themselves or the grainy shadows). The style I am looking for specifically includes:

- Few colours, but vivid ones, often used abstractly (see the third example: the skin colour is reused on the shoes and roses, and as a detail on the trousers). Also gradients sometimes appear, especially to indicate depth.
- Grainy/noisy shadows, sometimes looking like a paintbrush stroke (see the details in the fourth example)
- Disproportionate shapes, usually people with big bodies and small heads (the last example demonstrates this well, although it is not coloured too interestingly). Shapes are (almost) always curved/rounded off: never completely sharp.

I would like to get a name for this style, and I'd be interested in any resources talking about making it yourself. I think it gives off a certain feel that I would really like to replicate, but am unsure how to start, partially because I don't know the name/what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this same question [a few times recently](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style-identification?tab=Newest). There's no name for it, really, ok its a "trend" right now, everybody seems to be doing it, but nobody gave it an actual name.

This guy Cosmin Serban sure does use the term **flat illustration** alot on his Youtube channel where you probably have that second screenshot from. The name **flat 2.0 illustration** seems to be used by other people. Since you're looking for training on this, his very channel is probably what you need really.

Comment: Yes, this question comes up incredibly often. I somewhat understand the desire to know "the name" of this style, but then again it might not be so helpful. Different artists follow this trend of clean vector drawing with textures, but they all try to be *original* within this style. If you want to draw things like this it would be helpful to know how to technically draw vector shapes and add textures, but then you get to a point where you have to actually *draw* the shapes yourself. I don't think any tutorial will help there. Just practice drawing and maybe copy some of the drawings you like.